# Custom/Own Views in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am trying to develop an e-commerce application. I have my application's view pages as standalone HTML pages(neatly formatted with images and styling as I need) and I am trying to plug them into an e-commerce package. My e-commerce application has a simple workflow -> Customer adds products to cart and check out followed with order confirmation.

Now my question is how do I add that those existing view pages to opencart? I tried to load view from controller but the error says page not found.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would be glad, if that user who voted down can also explain something? Voting down without reason is against the law.

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific. Please upvote and reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

most e-commerce solutions are php based because you are most likely incorporating a database with your products.  Unless you want to develop your own solution from scratch, it is easier to use an existing platform and create a customized template.
I have found that zencart is the easiest to create custom templates for, but that is just my personal opinion

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more, please? Does zencart enable me to plug-in my existing HTML view pages?

Comment: No it does not, to my knowledge there is no e-commerce solution that will allow you to "plug-in" your existing html. You will have to create your own template based on the platform you choose

Comment: Thanks Keith. Atleast you pointed me in right direction. I changed my question to be more specific to opencart now.

Comment: @stackSamaritan you will have to edit the .tpl files